# NopCommerce - OutPutCaching not working on Parent Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, output-caching

If I apply `[OutputCache(Duration = 600)]` on Any Child action `[ChildActionOnly]` it works just fine. but if Apply caching on a main action.
It will keep hitting the action every time I refresh the page.

I created a new controller which inherits MVC "`BaseController`" instead of inheriting  Nopcommerce "`BasePublicController`".
But still no Luck.

```
public class CacheController : BaseController
    {
        [ OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
        public ActionResult testCache( )
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Now if I create a brand new an independent MVC project  caching works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

MVC Outout caching will not on Parent actions. It will work for child actions only. You can use [this](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3) plugin for Parent Actions.